# VSCode theme color for PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I prefer VSCode over Sublime (mostly because TypeScript). Can a VSCode color theme for PHP differentiate between classes, functions and properties? I have tried a few themes without any success.

Should this question be posted somewhere else? It seems not to fit here but I'm not so sure where to post it. Also, there is not a single occurrence on google about the topic, so I think both the question and the answer will reach a lot of php programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class`, `public` and `function` are all colored using the `keyword` scope and they don't have any more specific scopes, meaning it's not possible to differentiate them. To support this, the PHP language tokenizer would need to support more specific scopes.

I went ahead and [created a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3951) on the GitHub repository.